# Possibility to override DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()?

Tags: java, date, scjp

I just wonder, is it possible to tell our JVM to use a default DateFormat that is not the one configured for the current locale for exemple?

I know I can provide the Locale but I don't want to.

Actually, I would like to be able to specify the DateFormat to be returned for a specific locale.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes to my mind here is to "hijack" the java.text.DateFormat class. To do this, you would need to write your own class of the same package and name, compile it into a jar and place that jar into the JRE's lib\endorsed folder.

Disclaimer:
I haven't tested this, and I'm pretty sure it constitutes a violation of some rule, it may not work, and it may delete the entire contents of your disk.

Other than that: Why would you want to do this? If you want to change the date format for your system's locale, go to the system's control center and change it for every locale you like ;-)